# Using .apk files to reverse_tcp and exploit on android?

Tags: exploit, android

I have been able to install and run the application that I plan on exploiting.  Once the app is running I am able to exploit the application.  In my testing environment I am able to do this just fine.  I use the following steps:

1. Download **astro file manager**
2. Find the `.apk` file & install
3. Run the application
4. Exploit the application

But now I want to replicate this in a more realistic scenario.  Assuming a user as installed my application on their phone, how can I ensure that my application is running in order to enable exploitation?  Is there a way that I can make my application run infinitely in the background without the Android OS closing my app due to resource management?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Consider reading about common mobile vulenrablites: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Projects/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project_-_Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks

Comment: Through social engineering for example. You can trick your pentest target into installing the apk after sending him an e-mail with it.

Comment: I rephrased the question to clarify.  If this has changed your meaning you can rollback the edit.

Comment: just for curiosity, is there other ways to install the `apk` file besides  social media ? I've seen  for example you can use **market.android.com**  to install applications on **your** phone as long as you sign into you **google account** so say  the you get the target's google account & passord and then install. but I believe that this proceedure only works with *legal* applications, thus you wouldn´t be able to upload the `apk` file into **google market apps**

Comment: Plus **unkown** applications won't install unless the phone has enabled unknown resources.